# error using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

The code is not running. However instead of i^2 in the second term if I use i then it is working. But with i^2 fails.

```
    Xmax = 500; Tmax = 1; eqn = 
 Table[Subscript[u, i]'[
    t] == (2*(Subscript[u, i + 1][t] - 2 Subscript[u, i][t] + 
         Subscript[u, i - 1][t]) + (i i - 
         Sum[i i Subscript[u, i][t], {i, -Xmax, Xmax}]) Subscript[u, 
         i][t])/Sum[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, -Xmax, Xmax}], {i, 
   1 - Xmax, Xmax - 1}]

bcs = {Subscript[u, -Xmax][t] == 0, Subscript[u, Xmax][t] == 0}; iv = 
 Table[If[(i >= -10) && (i <= 10), Subscript[u, i][0] == 1/21, 
   Subscript[u, i][0] == 0], {i, -Xmax, Xmax}]; s = 
 NDSolveValue[{eqn, iv, bcs}, 
  Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, -Xmax + 1, Xmax - 1}], {t, 0, 
   Tmax}]; {Plot[s, {t, 0, Tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"t", u}], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[s, {t, 0, Tmax}], AxesLabel -> {x, u}, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

Comment: This works, for example, for Xmax = 15

Comment: What do you mean by "not running"?  Does it return an error, or is it just not returning an answer promptly? If you're trying to solve a system of 999 coupled non-linear ODEs, you shouldn't expect an instantaneous result.

Comment: No I understand but it is showing error namely  "At t == 0.019485983068404454`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected".

Comment: and i cant set Xmax small because then it will give junk answer.